# How to choose Full Frames (Uncompressed) as codec for VideoWriter

Tags: opencv, kinect, video-capture, emgucv, codec

i want to store uncompressed frames from a device as a video, but i need to know how to choose " Full Frames (Uncompressed) " as a codec for the VideoWriter (in emgu aka openCV).

Iam able to choose it from the dropdown menu when iam passing -1 like this

```
VideoWriter myVideoWriter = new VideoWriter ("myVieoColor.avi", -1 , 15, videoSize, true);
```

But i want to choose the Full Frames (Uncompressed) codec automatically.
For example i know i can choose the Lagarith Lossless Video Codec by

```
VideoWriter myVideoWriter = new VideoWriter ("myVieoColor.avi", Emgu.CV.VideoWriter.Fourcc('L','A','G','S') , 15, videoSize, true);
```

but iam not able to figure out which fourcc i need to use.

Perhaps someone can help me out please

Answer (score 5):

If we break into debugger when this codec selection dialog box is open, we can see that it's the result of [this call](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/videoio/src/cap_vfw.cpp#L792) to `AVISaveOptions(...)`. So, one way to find out what you picked would be to set a breakpoint on say [line 799](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/videoio/src/cap_vfw.cpp#L799) and inspect the contents of `fourcc`.

However, there is even simpler way:

1. Create a dummy video **foo.avi** with just 1 black frame, selecting the codec using the GUI.
2. Open **foo.avi** using `cv::VideoCapture`.
3. Get the `CAP_PROP_FOURCC` from the `cv::VideoCapture` instance.
4. Decode and print it.
5. [Optional] Create a dummy video **bar.avi** with just 1 black frame, and use the FOURCC code you determined in step 3. Compare **foo.avi** and **bar.avi** to verify they are the same.

Sorry, I don't use C#/EmguCV, so I can't provide you an exact example, but the following should be easy enough to port.

### C++ Sample

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    {
        cv::VideoWriter outputVideo;
        outputVideo.open("foo.avi", -1, 25.0, cv::Size(640, 480), true);

        cv::Mat frame(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
        outputVideo.write(frame);
    }

    cv::VideoCapture inputVideo("foo.avi");
    int fourcc = static_cast<int>(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));

    char FOURCC_STR[] = {
        (char)(fourcc & 0XFF)
        , (char)((fourcc & 0XFF00) >> 8)
        , (char)((fourcc & 0XFF0000) >> 16)
        , (char)((fourcc & 0XFF000000) >> 24)
        , 0
    };
    std::cout << "FOURCC is '" << FOURCC_STR << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
FOURCC is 'DIB '
```

### Python Sample

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import struct

outputVideo = cv2.VideoWriter()
outputVideo.open("foo.avi", -1, 25, (640,480), True)

frame = np.zeros((480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8)
outputVideo.write(frame)
outputVideo.release()

inputVideo = cv2.VideoCapture("foo.avi")
fourcc = int(inputVideo.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC))

print "FOURCC is '%s'" % struct.pack("<I", fourcc)
```

Console output:

```
FOURCC is 'DIB '
```

Comment: Feel free to add a C# sample to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

From Opencv Reference

Tips:

->With some backends fourcc=-1 pops up the codec selection dialog from the system.

->To save image sequence use a proper filename (eg. img_%02d.jpg) and fourcc=0 OR fps=0. Use uncompressed image format (eg. img_%02d.BMP) to save raw frames.

->Most codecs are lossy. If you want lossless video file you need to use a lossless codecs (eg. FFMPEG FFV1, Huffman HFYU, Lagarith LAGS, etc...)

->If FFMPEG is enabled, using codec=0; fps=0; you can create an uncompressed (raw) video file.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#afec93f94dc6c0b3e28f4dd153bc5a7f0

Answer (score 1):

Well Thank you a lot.

I thought about a similar way but missed the functions in emgu ( the VideoWriter nor the Capture got a get(CAP_PROB) function, but thanks to you i searched a bit more around and found the CvInvoke.cveVideoCaptureGet function.

Now iam able to write the video as i did before read the Video file with the Capture class and use the functiion above.

```
//record the Videofile with VideoWriter to "myVideoColor.avi"
capture = new Capture("myVieoColor.avi");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CvInvoke.cveVideoCaptureGet(capture, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FourCC));
```

So far so good.
When i using LAGS as codec everything works just fine and i get 1397178700,so i can call the constructor with this value instead.

```
VideoWriter myVideoWriter = new VideoWriter ("myVieoColor.avi", 1397178700 , 15, videoSize, true);
//works great with 1397178700 == LAGS codec
```

But when i pass -1 and choose uncompressed from drop down menu it gives me back 0 as fourCC codec value, but when using 0 as constructor param, it wont record and print 808596553 as value for the used codec

```
VideoWriter myVideoWriter = new VideoWriter ("myVieoColor.avi", 0 , 15, videoSize, true);
//dont work and CapProb.FourCC returns 808596553
```

Choosing Lagarith Lossless Codec from drop gives me 1397178700 as it should and will work.
So any ideas?

PS: Thanks again for your help so far Dan Mašek